# Any examples/tutorials on using Google GData API - Youtube on iphone?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, youtube, gdata-api

I need to list a specific users uploaded videos (YouTube) in a UITableView. I've downloaded the GData source and example projects (not iphone specific) but I can't seem to get it to work. Does anybody know of any good (or any at all ;)) tutorials out there?

Best regards,
Magnus

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming you have included the GData client libraries to your project, you need to make a call to fetch the user's uploads, and then display them. Here's the simplest way I can think of:

Create an instance variable in your table view controller class that will hold the feed data returned from the YouTube API.

#### RootViewController.h

```
#import "GDataYouTube.h"
#import "GDataServiceGoogleYouTube.h"

@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController {
    GDataFeedYouTubeVideo *feed;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) GDataFeedYouTubeVideo *feed;
```

Inside the implementation file, make a call to the API to fetch all uploaded videos. Inside the callback selector `request:finishedWithFeed:error`, store the results in whatever format suits, and reload the table view. In the table views `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, format the cell as desired:

#### RootViewController.m

```
// get the youtube service
GDataServiceGoogleYouTube *service = [self youTubeService];

// feed id for user uploads
NSString *uploadsID = kGDataYouTubeUserFeedIDUploads;
// construct the feed url
NSURL *feedURL = [GDataServiceGoogleYouTube youTubeURLForUserID:@"annoyingorange"
                                            userFeedID:uploadsID];

// make API call
[service fetchFeedWithURL:feedURL
         delegate:self
         didFinishSelector:@selector(request:finishedWithFeed:error:)];
```

Checkout the [full source code](http://pastebin.com/vmV2c0HT) for RootViewController.

Comment: Great! That example solved exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!
/M

Comment: if the user credentials are invalid and the login fails, is there a callback that I can use to give the user an error msg? I'm trying to understand the GData api for Google Docs and I'm confused. I obtain the docService in which I use [service setUserCredentialsWithUsername:username password:pwd]; but I don't know what happens when the login fails for some reason.

Comment: This is brilliant thank you. Everyone else points you to the docs and the GData example projects which can quite frankly be quite overwhelming. This however, is understandable, thanks.

Comment: how do i includ the GData client libraries to my project?