# @selector() not working? youtube API GData issues

Tags: iphone, youtube-api, gdata

I'm trying to integrate GData/YouTubeAPI into my project but I'm a bit stuck. I used the code that was given in this post:

[Any examples/tutorials on using Google GData API - Youtube on iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066131/any-examples-tutorials-on-using-google-gdata-api-youtube-on-iphone)

My problem is that the function 'request:finishedWithFeed:error:' is not called when the GData service is done grabbing data off the interwebs.

My program compiles and runs – and no runtime errors present themselves. I also checked and feedURL returns a valid URL. I debugged this and 'service' does manage to return a value.

```
GDataServiceGoogleYouTube *service = [self youTubeService];

// feed id for user uploads
NSString *uploadsID = kGDataYouTubeUserFeedIDUploads;
// construct the feed url
NSURL *feedURL = [GDataServiceGoogleYouTube youTubeURLForUserID:USER_NAME userFeedID:uploadsID];

// make API call

[service fetchFeedWithURL:feedURL delegate:self didFinishSelector:@selector(request:finishedWithFeed:error:)];
```

This is the header for the function I'm trying to get service to call when its done, it's located in the same object as the other code i've posted

```
- (void)request:(GDataServiceTicket *)ticket finishedWithFeed:(GDataFeedBase *)aFeed error:(NSError *)error;
```

SOLUTION --

make sure its running on main thread --

```
-(id)initWithVideosArrayURLString:(NSString*)url {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        NSLog(@"loading");
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(initMainThreadWithURLString:)     withObject:url waitUntilDone:NO];

    }
    return self;
}

-(void)initMainThreadWithURLString:(NSString*)url {
    GDataServiceGoogleYouTube *service = [self youTubeService];

    NSString *uploadsID = kGDataYouTubeUserFeedIDUploads;
    NSURL *feedURL = [GDataServiceGoogleYouTube youTubeURLForUserID:@"annoyingorange" userFeedID:uploadsID];
    [service fetchFeedWithURL:feedURL delegate:self   didFinishSelector:@selector(serviceTicket:finishedWithFeed:error:)];
    NSLog(@"sent");
}

- (void)serviceTicket:(GDataServiceTicket *)ticket finishedWithFeed:(GDataFeedBase *)aFeed error:(NSError *)error {
        self.feed = (GDataFeedYouTubeVideo *)aFeed;

    NSLog(@"success.");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your code on the main thread, and returning to the run loop after initiating the fetch?  Callbacks occur only when the app's run loop is spinning.