# Can we used Google API & YouTube API for our commercial video streaming products?

Tags: iphone, youtube, google-api

we have to develop a commercial video streaming application for iPhone & within that app we are planning to integrate additional searching functionality for Google Video & You Tube. I want to know following points,

1. Where can i find the Google video API & You Tube API ?
2. Will there be any legal issue on Google Video & You Tube video integration on commercial products, Form whom we have to the approval? Is there any standard procedure on this

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any examples/tutorials on using Google GData API - Youtube on iphone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066131/any-examples-tutorials-on-using-google-gdata-api-youtube-on-iphone)

Comment: Aside from the API question, legal issues are beyond the scope of this site.

Answer (score 2):

You are allowed to do this but there are some restrictions

Take a look at the [Terms of Service Point 1.2 Commercial Usage](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/youtube/terms.html) and [Using the YouTube APIs to Build Monetizable Applications](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/youtube/creating_monetizable_applications.html) (too much to include in this answer)

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C APIs for Google services are at http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/

YouTube provides an API, including video searches; Google Video does not.

Google APIs are intended for use in commercial applications, but carefully read the [YouTube FAQ](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/faq.html) and the associated terms of services documents.