# How to integrate youtube to iphone

Tags: ios4, youtube

Can anyone help me? How to integrate youtube to iphone.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing Youtube videos on iphone (objective-c)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296597/accessing-youtube-videos-on-iphone-objective-c)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in 2 ways as explained here:

[Youtube Integration Guide](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2009/02/youtube-apis-iphone-cool-mobile-apps.html)