# GData + iphone app

Tags: iphone, gdata

I have a problem. I am trying to bind my iphone project with GData. Now I have alredy downloaded source code - http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client
and make this tutorial - http://mischneider.net/?p=377#comment-1277. But i get error:
**SCNetworkReachabilityScheduleWithRunLoop
referenced from:

-[GDataOAuthSignIn startReachabilityCheck]

in libGDataTouchStaticLib.a(GDataOAuthSignIn.o)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add the `SystemConfiguration` framework to your project.

To do that: right-click on the the frameworks group in your project and select "Add existing project", then scroll the list to find the `SystemConfiguration` and add it.

Comment: I don't have this file :(. You can send me tutorial - how to include GData. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, the name of the framework is `SystemConfiguration`. I have modified my answer.

Comment: Sorry! Can you send me tutorial how to serach and login with GDataYoutube? Thanks!

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066131/any-examples-tutorials-on-using-google-gdata-api-youtube-on-iphone

Comment: Hi! I have new problem! How get video url from fetched feed entries.

Comment: If you have a new problem, you should ask a new question.

Comment: Hi! I have new problem! How get video url from fetched feed entries

(I want get url at selected row in uitableview like this:

GDataEntryBase *entry = [[feed entries] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];    
NSArray *thumbnails = [[(GDataEntryYouTubeVideo *)entry mediaGroup] mediaThumbnails];
NSLog([[thumbnails objectAtIndex:0] URLString]);
)